# Javascript Syntax Error

Tags: javascript

hiere is my code, within a loop.
I want to solve my closure problem.
But on click I receive an error message "Syntac Error".
Any help. Thanks in advance.

```
var html  = '<div style="margin-top:10px">';
    html += '<div class="weiter">  Kartenauswahl in die Recherche &uuml;bernehmen </div>';
    html += '<div class="weiter" style="display:block;clear:left;margin-top:7px" 
              onclick="function(obj) { return getChildObject(obj)}(obj)">Weiter</div>';
    html += '</div>';
```

Comment: Instead of using string to create your dom, you could create DOM objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code in your `onclick` attribute is not valid:

```
function(obj) { return getChildObject(obj)}(obj)
```

Put the function expression in parentheses and try this instead:

```
(function(obj) { return getChildObject(obj); })(obj)
```

Comment: +1 Although in this case OP could simply use `return getChildObject(obj);`.

Answer (score 3):

This certainly does not look right:

```
function(obj) { return getChildObject(obj)}(obj)
```

I would simply write this:

```
return getChildObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's your actual code, the immediate problem is that there's a line break in your string literal, between the third and fourth lines. Delete that line break. There are problems in the HTML too, as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be at:

```
onclick="function(obj) { return getChildObject(obj)}(obj)
                                                      ^
```

Try removing `(obj)`.

Also you should post the code for `getChildObject` function.

Answer (score 0):

function(obj) { return getChildObject(obj)}(obj)

Above does not seems to be correct